# Dynamically switch ng-include between controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing, angularjs-ng-include

I have the following bit of code for my navigation that I want to update dynamically between pages.

```
<nav ng-include="menuPath"></nav>
```

Here is my app and routing set up

```
var rxApp = angular.module('ehrxApp', ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
rxApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller: 'mainController',
            templateUrl: '/content/views/index.html'
        })
        .when('/census', {
            templateUrl: '/content/views/admission/census.html',
            controller: 'censusController'
        })
        .when('/messages', {
            templateUrl: '/content/views/account/messages.html',
            controller: 'messagesController'
        })
        .when('/profile', {
            templateUrl: '/content/views/account/profile.html',
            controller: 'profileController'
        })
});
```

In my main controller I set the menuPath value here:

```
rxApp.controller('mainController', function (userService, $scope, $http) {
    evaluate_size();

    $scope.menuPath = "/content/views/index.menu.html";
});

rxApp.controller('censusController', function ($scope, $http, $sce, censusService) {
    $scope.menuPath = "/content/views/admission/census.menu.html";
    evaluate_size();

});
```

When the page switches to the census view it should change the menu.  What happens though is the first page loads the main menu, then no matter what other page you go to the menu never updates.

Comment: would need to know more about your html to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine this problem has something to do with a primitive values and prototypical inheritance between child scopes, but would need to see more of your html to determine that.  Without that, I propose an alternative way that may solve your problem and keep the config all in one place.

$routeProvider will accept variables and keep them on the route, even if angular doesn't use them. so we modify your routing by including the menuPath like so:

```
var rxApp = angular.module('ehrxApp', ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
rxApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller: 'mainController',
            templateUrl: '/content/views/index.html',
            menuPath: '/content/views/index.menu.html'
        })
        .when('/census', {
            templateUrl: '/content/views/admission/census.html',
            controller: 'censusController',
            menuPath: '/content/views/admission/census.menu.html'
        })
        .when('/messages', {
            templateUrl: '/content/views/account/messages.html',
            controller: 'messagesController'
        })
        .when('/profile', {
            templateUrl: '/content/views/account/profile.html',
            controller: 'profileController'
        })
});
```

Remove setting $scope.menuPath from each controller, then finally add a watch on rootScope that will change the menuPath on $routeChangeSuccess

```
rxApp.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current) {
        if (current && current.$$route && current.$$route.menuPath) {
            $rootScope.menuPath = current.$$route.menuPath;
        } else {
            $rootScope.menuPath = '';
        }
    });
}]);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I'm still new to Angular, so some of these tricks I haven't learned yet.